# Ubuntu server cant ping outside network &| DNS (Temporary failure in name resolution)

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

My network on the server is not working, help much appreciated

```
default via 192.168.50.1 dev eno1 proto static 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.50.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.88
```

I can ping my router 192.168.50.1 and it does answer

I have tried many different netplan and resolve.conf configurations without any success..

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:14:b1:38:2d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.50.88  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
        inet6 fe80::86a9:3eff:fe11:7ef6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 84:a9:3e:11:7e:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4563  bytes 667639 (667.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5702  bytes 6573527 (6.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xb1200000-b1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15062  bytes 2578348 (2.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15062  bytes 2578348 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**UPDATE: So it seems netplan was the issue, i was able to get my connection back without static config for netplan. I still can not get static working ...**

Netplan file: 00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.50.88/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.50.1
```

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Feb 16 16:13 /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13311ms
```

```
resolvectl status
Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
Fallback DNS Servers: 8.8.4.4

Link 2 (eno1)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

```
more /etc/resolv.conf 
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).

nameserver 8.8.8.8
search .
```

```
uname -a
Linux server 5.15.0-94-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 15:25:40 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
dig google.com
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: timed out
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: timed out
```

Comment: for awareness for "routes" you don't need that if you're using DHCP4 because that will define your routes and gateway.   You should not define those routes yourself unless you're doing static addressing.  Is this on some kind of managed firewall network or such which has much more restrictive handling of traffic rather than a standard off the shelf network router?

Comment: Its all standard, ive tried to reset netplan and router to default settings without success, bit lost on what to do next.

Comment: Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` You have omitted nameservers. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you @chili555, i was able to get my connection back when resetting netplan to default values (not static), but cant seem to get static working. I will update question.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl status` and `systemctl status systemd-resolved`. Also, show output of `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @mpboden updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 netplan static routes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062902/ubuntu-18-04-netplan-static-routes)

Comment: This new info shows a few things. First, `/etc/resolv.conf` is typically a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. The fact that it's not indicates you've replaced the symlink with a static file. The output of `resolvectl status` indicates this as well where it says `resolv.conf mode: foreign`. Next, what's more concerning is that you're unable to `ping 8.8.8.8`. If you can ping your gateway at `192.168.50.1`, but can't ping outside your internal network, this indicates a router problem.

Comment: Here is what to do about resolv.conf: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469052/no-internet-in-ubuntu-22-04-editing-etc-resolv-conf-brings-back-internet-but/1469213#1469213 Now do your pings work?